# How can I align this text under an image when both are displayed using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce

I have PHP code for a cart system that displays category pictures and then displays the title of the category under each picture. The text is currently aligned on the left under the picture. I want to center the text under the picture. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
?>
<h3>
<?php
    echo $category->name;
?>
```

Where:

```
echo $category->name;
```

is the code that displays the title text under the image. How can I center align that portion?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: well you have indicated `css` as one of your tags. atleast try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively, I would try the CSS equivalent of:

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">
```

or use a CSS rule if you can isolate the `h3` tag of interest.

You need to either modify the relevant template file or CSS file,
whatever you are most comfortable with.

**Note:**  Just be aware that if you modify the template or CSS files, they could get overwritten if your application were to be upgraded to a newer version.  Keep extra copies of the modified files in a safe place with some notes about the fix.  You will thank yourself a year from now.

Comment: That worked. Not sure why 3 people down voted my question when the answer was that simple. I'm ignorant to how CSS and HTML work in PHP files.

Comment: @BlueRiver89 CSS and HTML work like CSS and HTML no matter what language you use

Comment: 3 down votes is a bit excessive in my opinion, your question is more on the conceptual size of the spectrum, but nevertheless, valid, at least you got the help that you needed, good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your update. I'm gonna back up all the files now since I put it in the php template file, as I can see what you mean.